# Restrictions on coefficient of a concave function

Tags: functions

Suppose $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f'>0, f''<0$ 
 $\forall x>0, f(0)=0, f(x)\rightarrow 1 \text{ as } x \rightarrow +\infty.$  Also, I am given $f(10)=q$ where $q$ is a constant.  
Given $r>0, \exists x>0$ s.t. $rf(x)=f(20)$.  What restrictions, if any, must $r$ necessarily have?

I understand that if $r$ is smaller (larger), $x$ would be chosen correspondingly to be larger (smaller) for the equality to hold since $f$ is increasing.  It also occurred to me that since $f$ is concave, $f(20)<2f(10)=2q$, but I am not sure if this determines any restriction on $r$.  Alternatively, is there another relation I am missing here that would lead to a necessary restriction on $r$?

Comment: You need to place a lower bound on $r$ of the type $r>c$ (for a particular constant $c$). Can you find $c$ and then prove optimality by jiggling the concave function?

Comment: PS: The inequality $f(20) < 2q$ is true but not helpful for this problem.  Rather, you will need a lower bound on $f(20)$.